# HTML5 Recording

Tags: javascript, html, video-recording

I'm trying to record video using html5 .getUserMedia and then play it again without upload to the server. I have tried many tutorial and I made it work in Chrome by using canvas to draw the webp image and then convert to the webm by using Whammy.js . But the problem is it did not work on Firefox that unsupported webp. I just want to make it work in Firefox.

Any idea possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intrestingly firefox supports direct webm recordings, have you tried [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC),
you can check the demo [here](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/AudioVideo-on-Firefox.html).